# missing ; before statement [Break On This Error] <!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">

Tags: html, jsp, layout, jspx

Why I'm getting this error in one of my jspx layouts

[image: Screenshot of an error seen in firebug console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging a little I found the reason 
Here is my test template to reproduce it

```
    <html 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
    xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" 
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" 
    xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" >  

    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />  
    <jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" /> 

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />    

        <spring:url context="" value="resources/js/test.js" var="testX_js" />
        <script src="${test_js}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ><!-- //required for FF3 and Opera --></script>

        <spring:message code="application_name" var="app_name" htmlEscape="false"/>
        <title><spring:message code="welcome_h3" arguments="${app_name}" /></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span>TEST</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now look when the js file is included "testX_js"

```
<spring:url context="" value="resources/js/slideshow.js" var="testX_js" />
<script src="${test_js}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ><!-- //required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
```

The name testX_js does not match test_js and this was the cause of an error.
I had to make that typo when including new script 
So folks make sure that the variable with the url to your script is not empty

Cheers

Comment: This seems a little localized given that the error arose from a typo and nothing more. For all we know, there can be a wide range of common causes for such an error, and a typo seems all too unlikely to be useful to a wide audience.

Comment: Maybe but it took me a while to figure this out and I want to share this with others. The layout I was working on was big and included many js files Spotting the typo was not an easy task as I had to eliminate pieces of the layout one by one to track it down. Maybe this answer will save someone else time by giving indication where to look for